# Como referenciar múltiplas chaves estrangeiras em um campo MYSQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Estou com um problema que não consigo achar solução, estou fazendo um banco de dados para um sistema escolar, nesse sistema existe a tabela das materias, que possui um ID e um NOME, e os professores que possuem um ID um NOME e a referencia para as materias que eles ministram.

```
CREATE TABLE db_materias(
id int(4) not null auto_increment,
name varchar(20) not null
primary key(id)
);

CREATE TABLE db_professores(
id int(4) not null auto_increment,
name varchar(20) not null
materias int(4)
primary key(id)

foreign key(materias) references db_materias(id)
);
```

O problema é que, existem ocasiões que o mesmo professor ministra **múltiplas** matérias, consigo fazer o professor ter uma matéria mas não consigo varias, de primeira pensei em criar um array para guardar isso, mas descobri que o MYSQL não tem arrays, pensei também em criar varias colunas para matérias mas acredito que não seja o modo mais eficiente de se resolver.
Não consigo achar em lugar algum uma maneira de resolver esse tipo de situação, estou começando a aprender sobre databases, não tenho experiencia com o topico.
Agradeço a ajuda, obrigado.

Comment: O usual para modelar tal situação (um relacionamento N:N) é criar uma outra tabela que relacione cada professor a cada matéria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer esse tipo de relação eu utilizaria outra tabela que seria matérias ministradas professor com os campos matérias podendo ser null assim você poderá fazer o relacionamento com a materias

```
CREATE TABLE db_materias_professor(
id int(4) not null auto_increment,
professor int(4) not null
materia_a int(4)
materia_b int(4)
materia_c int(4)
materia_d int(4)
primary key(id)

foreign key(professor) references db_professores(id)
foreign key(materia_a) references db_materias(id)
foreign key(materia_b) references db_materias(id)
foreign key(materia_c) references db_materias(id)
foreign key(materia_d) references db_materias(id)
);
```

e troque a referencia da tabela db_professores
de

```
foreign key(materias) references db_materias(id)
```

para

```
foreign key(materias) references db_materias_professor(id)
```

Comment: Não seria muito mais prático, e muito melhor, a tabela de relacionamento conter apenas o par (professor, disciplina)? Dois relacionamentos 1:N modelam perfeitamente o que foi descrito.

Comment: Funciona também só mudaria a forma de se chamar os relacionamentos no meu caso teria campos com null e no seu caso não porem teria que chamar todos os relacionamentos e sub relacionamentos e também não teria mais a referencia em db_professores

Comment: E se no futuro você quisesse acrescentar uma quinta matéria para um professor teria que modificar a definição de seu banco de dados e recria-lo?

Comment: No caso você teria que apenas fazer um `ALTER TABLE db_materias_professor
ADD CONSTRAINT `materia_e ` FOREIGN KEY (`db_materias`) 
REFERENCES `db_materias`(`id`)

Comment: Recomendo que você dê uma estudada em modelagem de dados.